# System Object Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a form that has a few buttons, one button allows me to create multiple new forms (form2 with a textbox, the button creates a new instance of this form everytime it is clicked.)

My issue is that I keep getting the exception `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TextDocument'.'`

I am also not able to create multiple forms with my button, it creates one instance that I can save and open, but I am unable to create anymore.

I did declare a new form being made, gave it a name, etc.  Which looks like this

```
  public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        TextDocument Text;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text = new TextDocument();
        }
```

In my first form(main form which is an mdi form) I have the following code for my button.

```
private void btnNewTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Text.MdiParent = this;
           Text.Show();
       }
```

In my second form below, which is called TextDocument, all I have is

```
 public string TextFileName
        {
            get { return tbText.Text; }
            set { tbText.Text = value; }      
        }
```

Which I do not think should be an issue as all I am doing is gathering text for my save button which works perfectly fine.

Overall what I am trying to do is have a button that when clicked I can create a new instance of form2 which is called Text.  But I keep getting the exception `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'TextDocument'.'`and I am unsure how to fix this.

(this is the first programming language I have been working on for the last 3 months, so any help is very much appreciated.).

Comment: Try putting Text= new TextDocument(); in btnNewTool_Click event before calling Te.MdiParent = this;

Comment: Everytime you create a new `TextDocument` you are writing it over the previous one by assigning it to the same variable. If an object is no longer assigned to a variable it is considered out of scope and is disposed and cleaned up by the garbage collector. If you didn't you would max out your memory space with objects you can no longer reference, also known as a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDI means "Multiple Document Interface".  You wrote your code as a Single Document Interface.

Remove these lines:

```
TextDocument Text;
Text = new TextDocument();
```

Your click event should look something like this:

```
private void btnNewTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextDocument td = new TextDocument();
   td.MdiParent = this;
   td.Show();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I am having issues with my savefiledialog now though, 
Specifically in the last bit where I have `writer.Write(TextFile.TextFileName);`  TextFile is being listed with an exception saying it does not exist in the current method, not quite sure how to fix this.

Comment: @Mark You didn't post that code.  It would be something like `writer.Write(((TextDocument)this.ActiveMdiChild).TextFileName);`  Check if ActiveMdiChild is null.  If not, you cast it to your TextDocument class in order to access the TextFileName property.

Comment: My apologies for not including it, but that seems to have done the trick, Thank you!